# Checking for minimum number of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two rows in my table bank like the ones below

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| branch_name | Name            |
+-------------+-----------------+
| ABCD        |Ron              |
| QWER        |Edward           |
| QWER        |Steve            |
| QWER        |Max              |
| ABCD        |John             |
| PQRS        |Nike             |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

My question is, How can I find the number of account holders (name), in each branch where there is a minimum of 3 account holders(names).

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, and `HAVING`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a query similar to:

```
select branch_name, count(Name) as num_accounts from bank group by branch_name having num_accounts > 3
```